# What Coffee to use for Cuban-inspired coffee?

Tags: ground-coffee, beans, recommendation

I have been drinking Cafe Bustelo espresso for over 20 years. What are some similar (flavor, boldness, caffeine, strength, & consistency) but better espresso options I can try?

This is the exact product I buy from them: [*Ground Espresso Coffee*](https://www.cafebustelo.com/en/coffee/ground/espresso-style-brick). It's a dark blend, Latin inspired (particularly Cuba), made with 100% Arabica beans, less of a caffeine kick but is also less bitter, and still has the distinctive full body of the regular blend. Some reviewers described it as:

> Densely bitter; heavy rather than full. Some sweet, raisin-like fruit struggles to get out from under the bitter weight of the cup.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee! That seems to be a specific brand which offers coffee products for different brewing methods (e.g. ground coffee, instant coffee). Can you say which kind of product you used and what characteristics you think the coffee has? One way to answer this question would be to recommend a roast level and bean origin. To make such a recommendation, we need to know what you're looking for. Let's assume the majority of users isn't familiar with that particular brand and its taste characteristics.

Comment: @JJJ Thank you! So this is the exact product I buy from them https://www.cafebustelo.com/en/coffee/ground/espresso-style-brick It is called "Ground Espresso Coffee". It's a dark blend, Latin inspired (particularly Cuba), made with 100% Arabica beans, less of a caffeine kick but is also less bitter, and still has the distinctive full body of the regular blend. Some reviewers described it as, "Densely bitter; heavy rather than full. Some sweet, raisin-like fruit struggles to get out from under the bitter weight of the cup." I hope this helps you help me!

Comment: Okay, I've gone ahead and edited that into your question. I'm still not sure if it makes sense to give a recommendation based on this. For starts the description seems a bit conflicted, on the one hand it's not too bitter but the other description says it's 'densely bitter'. I could give some more general advice like buying freshly roasted whole beans and grinding them for each brew. Also there are some tricks to understanding marketing terms use in coffee advertisements. Though that's far from a specific recommendation and it doesn't really take into account the coffee you mentioned.

Comment: When you mention Cuban coffee, I think more of the brewing method than the kind of beans used. For example, see this Wikipedia article on [Cuban espresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_espresso). That article also mentions Cafe Bustelo, and they do mention darker roasts and moka pots (as the brewing method).

Comment: Thank you. @JJJ Although I've been drinking it for 20 years I do not have the experience in descriptions, flavors, etc. I would like to learn more which is why I am posing this first question based on my experience. I look forward to the responses.